# Am I able to route/duplicate one request to multiple backend targets via Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure-application-gateway

- I'm trying to take one request and route it to multiple backend targets.
- I'm **NOT** trying to take one request and route it to one backend target via multiple rules as a lot of the App Gateway documentation suggests.

What I've tried:

- I've tried creating 2 of the same listener's (which isn't possible) so that I can create 2 different rules targeting different backend pools for each listener.
- I set up one rule with multiple backend target's but I'm unable to have the same path with different backend targets. I tried specifying a wildcard path and an explicit path but would get an HTTP error when making requests through App Gateway.

Is it possible to duplicate a request and send each copy to a different backend target?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work. I think you need a different pool for each listener.

Can you try creating a separate pool for each of your backends?
Then create a listener in that pool.
Then create a rule to do the forwarding.

Ian

Comment: I'm able to create a separate backend pool (one for target A, and another for target B), but not a separate Listener that's listening on the same path. I'm only allowed to have one Listener for one specific path.

Comment: Can you use different listener urls?  My understanding is you can use wildcards that point to the same url, but only one gets executed if you have multiple on the same listener.  Can you add the different wildcard URLS's per listener.

"Request Routing rules evaluation order
While using multi-site listeners, to ensure that the client traffic is routed to the accurate backend, it is important to have the request routing rules be present in the correct order."  truncated, but that section of the doc is what I am referring to.

Comment: But doesn't that mean only 1 Listener executes? If I could create 2 different listeners for the same path and have them both execute then I could have 1 request being routed to more than one backend. But from what you're saying, if I have 2 different Listeners with wildcard URLs for basically the same path, App Gateway will only choose 1 Listener to be executed.

Comment: This is the theory.    

Trying to fix the formatting, hangon.   

Imagine a url.  devsystem.url.com  
-pool1 - listener1 url - dev*em.url.com - single-rule -> target url1  
-pool2 - listener2 url - devs*em.url.com - single-rule -> target url2  
  
devsystem.url.com matches both listener urls. yes, only one rule per listener executed,  but both listeners fire for the same request.  

Would need to be tested!